# Fetching json data via XHR for dynamic smart rendering of dhtmlxgrid loops indefinitely

Tags: javascript, php, json, dhtmlx

I'm trying to fetch data when scrolling in a dhtmlxgrid with enableSmartRendering(). The initial load() works well, so the top part of the grid is readable. However, as soon as I scroll down to where I have no data and it tries to load more, the browser keeps firing the XHR request until I scroll back up again, with no more data populating the grid.

Javascript:

```
mygrid = new dhtmlXGridObject("grid");
mygrid.setImagePath("codebase/imgs/");
mygrid.setHeader("Col1,Col2");
mygrid.setInitWidths("100,200");
mygrid.setColAlign("right,left");
mygrid.setColTypes("ro,ro");
mygrid.enableSmartRendering(true, 20);
mygrid.init();
mygrid.load("test.php?anrop=ajax", "json");
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($_GET['posStart'])) {
    $start = $_GET['posStart'];
} else {
    $start = 0;
}
if (isset($_GET['count'])) {
    $c = $_GET['count'];
} else {
    $c = 20;
}
$data['total_count'] = 1000;
$data['pos'] = $start;
for ($i = $start;$i <= ($start + $c) && $i < 1000;$i++) {
    $data['rows'][$i]['id'] = $i;
    $data['rows'][$i]['data'][0] = $i;
    $data['rows'][$i]['data'][1] = "string";
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

[Link to short video showing the issue.](http://gfycat.com/SelfassuredShamelessIndianhare)

I have tried searching on this site and others without finding anyone encountering this exact problem. I got the problem when trying to add the dynamic smart rendering to an older piece of code and figured I'd make this simple, short version to make sure it's not something with the old code, and it's still not working, but I can't seem to figure the solution out on my own. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I eventually found a solution. I hadn't built the array correctly. This works:

```
$rows = array();
$temprows = array();
$rows['total_count'] = 1000;
$rows['pos'] = $start;
for ($i = $start;$i <= ($start + $c) && $i <= 1000;$i++) {
    $row = array();
    $data = array();
    $row['id'] = $i;
    $data[0] = $i;
    $data[1] = "string";
    $row['data'] = $data;
    array_push($temprows,$row);
}
$rows['rows'] = $temprows;
echo json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: Does this work for the free GPL version of DHTMLX? I'm trying to do this, but it loads just once and doesn't continue after scrolling down.

Comment: Seems to be for the pro version only, unfortunately. Source: http://docs.dhtmlx.com/grid__smart_rendering.html

Comment: There was some ambiguity, but information was updated after I [asked on the forum](http://forum.dhtmlx.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=49876). Thanks for getting back on this.